# jQuery dialog validation using jquery.validate()

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, jquery-ui-dialog

When I click on the submit button, it still submits the form without validating the fields. I looked on other solutions here too, but no question mentions about what to do in the click function on submit.

Here's my code: https://jsfiddle.net/ishtiaq156/an1xqoxz/

**Form**:

```
      $('#submitContact').click(function() {
        var customerId = $('#customerId').val();
        var formData = $('#addCustomerForm').serialize();

        $.ajax({
          url: "/abc/admin/customer/" + customerId + "/addContact",
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "json",

          data: formData,
          success: function(data) {
            location.reload();
          },
          failure: function(errMsg) {
            alert(errMsg);
          }

        });
      });
```

**JavaScript:**

```
 $('#submitContact').click(function() {
                var customerId = $('#customerId').val();
                var formData = $('#addCustomerForm').serialize();

                $.ajax({
                  url: "/abc/admin/customer/" + customerId + "/addContact",
                  type: "POST",
                  dataType: "json",

                  data: formData,
                  success: function(data) {
                    location.reload();
                  },
                  failure: function(errMsg) {
                    alert(errMsg);
                  }

                });
              });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I've done it in the past is adding a submit handler to the validation code which calls your ajax function. Then you can change your button to type="submit"

```
$('#addCustomerForm').validate({
    rules: {
        /* removed for brevity */
    },
    messages: {
        /* removed for brevity */
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        updateRecord();
        /* $("#dialog-form").dialog("close"); -  if using dialog */
    }
    /* ....add other options as needed */
});

function updateRecord() {
    var customerId = $('#customerId').val();
    var formData = $('#addCustomerForm').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/abc/admin/customer/" + customerId + "/addContact",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",

        data: formData,
        success: function(data) {
           location.reload();
        },
        failure: function(errMsg) {
           alert(errMsg);
        }
    });
}
```

Also, you can send all your form variables using data rather than adding some to the URL:

```
data: {
    customerId: customerId,
    addContact: "addContact",
    ...add other form fields 
}
```

Comment: Perfect. I needed those two things: submitHandler and input type as submit. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

you should post here console log

make sure you have included jquery validation plugin

[or download it](https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation/releases/tag/1.17.0)

Comment: Yes. I did added the jquery.validate.js and I can verify that it is loaded by clicking ctrl+p in Chrome dev tools. Also, there are no console errors to post.